# Google Drive API - Uploading from MediaFileUpload using blob

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file (pdf) to Google Drive via the v3 API, I want to create the file out of an attachment from an email. All the docs that I've found seem to rely on a local file where as I want to upload a blob.

Here is the essence of my code so far:

```
class MailHandler(InboundMailHandler):
  def receive(self, mail_message):
    logging.info("Received a message from: " + mail_message.sender)
    if hasattr(mail_message, 'attachments'):
      logging.info("Has attachments")
      for filename, filecontents in mail_message.attachments:
        file_blob = filecontents.payload.decode(filecontents.encoding)
        credentials = UserModel.query().get()
        media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype = 'image/jpg')
        file = drive.files().create( body = {'name': 'testupload.jpg'}, media_body = media)
        file.execute(c.credentials.authorize(http))
```

Which throws an error, due the file not existing, which it doesn't because it is a blob.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, the key was to use the `MediaInMemoryUpload` from the `apiclient.http` module, which I found by inspecting `http`.

Here's a rough outline of how to use it:

```
from apiclient.http import MediaInMemoryUpload
media = MediaInMemoryUpload(file_blob, mime_type, resumable=True)
file = drive.files().create(body={'name': filename},media_body=media)
file.execute()
```

Comment: "DEPRECATED: Use MediaIoBaseUpload with either io.TextIOBase or StringIO for the stream."

Answer (score -2):

Try this [UploaderForGoogleDrive](https://gist.github.com/DrPaulBrewer/eaea4ad927389643e56ce566d4ed513e) sample on how to upload blob files to Drive API by DrPaulBrewer:

snippet:

```
**
     * Helper class for resumable uploads using XHR/CORS. Can upload any Blob-like item, whether
     * files or in-memory constructs.
     *
     * @example
     * var content = new Blob(["Hello world"], {"type": "text/plain"});
     * var uploader = new MediaUploader({
     *   file: content,
     *   token: accessToken,
     *   onComplete: function(data) { ... }
     *   onError: function(data) { ... }
     * });
     * uploader.upload();
```

Check the link for the whole code implementation.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this is a client side javascript function and I'm asking about a server side python problem?